# volemont/insights:chart.EquityCurve.R: a bug in graphing peaks of cumulative return?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, quantstrat

I came cross a function of graphing cumulative return of a strategy and the peaks of the return in a great example of combining shiny and quantstrat, thanks to Simon Otziger. The source code is [here](https://github.com/volemont/insights/blob/master/R/chart.EquityCurve.R). The code works fine most of time, but for some data it won't graph the peaks properly.

The code is simplified but the key logic is not changed. I ran the code with three set of data (cumPNL1, cumPNL2, cumPNL3) copied from three example strategies, in which the first data will cause the code to fail to graph peaks properly.

I ran the following codes with cumPNL1, cumPNL2, cumPNL3 separately. with both cumPNL2 and cumPNL3 the code can produce cumulative return line and peak points successfully. however, with cumPNL1 the code can only produce line, but peaks are not at the right positions.

I noticed that both peakIndex based on cumPNL2 and cumPNL3 have their first value being TRUE, so when I change the code by adding a line `peakIndex[1] <- TRUE`, cumPNL1 will work fine with the modified code.

Though now it works with modified code, I have no idea why it is behaving like this. Could anyone have a look? Thanks

```
cumPNL1 <- c(-193,-345,-406,-472,-562,-543,-450,-460,-544,-659,-581,-342,-384,276,-858,-257.99)
cumPNL2 <- c(35.64,4.95,-2.97,-6.93,11.88,-19.8,-26.73,-39.6,-49.5,-50.49,-51.48,-48.51,-50.49,-55.44,143.55,770.22,745.47,691.02,847.44,1141.47,1007.82,1392.93,1855.26,1863.18,2536.38,2778.93,2811.6,2859.12,2417.58)
cumPNL3 <- c(35.64,4.95,-2.97,-6.93,11.88,-19.8,-26.73,-39.6,-49.5,-50.49,-51.48,-48.51,-50.49,-55.44,143.55,770.22,745.47,691.02,847.44,1141.47,1007.82,1392.93,1855.26,1863.18,2536.38,2778.93,2811.6,2859.12,2417.58)


peakIndex <- c(cumPNL3[1] > 0, diff(cummax(cumPNL3)) > 0)
# peakIndex[1] <- TRUE

dev.new()

plot(cumPNL3, type='n', xlab="index of trades", ylab="returns in cash", main="cumulative returns and peaks")
grid()
lines(cumPNL3)    
points(cbind(1 : length(cumPNL3), cumPNL3)[peakIndex, ], 
       pch=19, col='green', cex=0.6)

legend(
    x='bottomright', inset=0.1,
    legend=c('Net Profit','Peaks'),
    lty=c(1, NA), pch=c(NA, 19),
    col=c('black','green')
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cumPNL1` has a single peak and R reduces the dimension from a numerical matrix to a numerical vector of length 2. The `points` function plots the two numerical vector values on the y-axis using the x-axis index 1 and 2:

```
peakIndex1 <- c(cumPNL1[1] > 0, diff(cummax(cumPNL1)) > 0)
peakIndex3 <- c(cumPNL3[1] > 0, diff(cummax(cumPNL3)) > 0)

str(cbind(1 : length(cumPNL1), cumPNL1)[peakIndex1,])
str(cbind(1 : length(cumPNL3), cumPNL3)[peakIndex3,])
```

Output:

```
> str(cbind(1 : length(cumPNL1), cumPNL1)[peakIndex1,])
 num [1:12, 1:2] 1 15 16 19 20 22 23 24 25 26 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "" "cumPNL1"
> str(cbind(1 : length(cumPNL3), cumPNL3)[peakIndex3,])
 Named num [1:2] 14 276
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "" "cumPNL3"
```

Usually setting `plot = FALSE` preserves the object, e.g., `str(cbind(1 : length(cumPNL3), cumPNL3)[peakIndex3, drop = FALSE])`, which somehow does not work in this case. However, changing the `points` line to the following fixes the problem:

```
points(seq_along(cumPNL3)[peakIndex], cumPNL3[peakIndex], pch = 19, 
  col = 'green', cex = 0.6)
```

Thanks for reporting the issue. I will push the fix to GitHub tomorrow.